# write to a file whose name begins with an uppercase letter

Tags: python

I've been googling this and can only find tutorials about scanning files for words beginning with upper case letters.

However I have the following function

```
def writeToFile(filename, target, moves, layout ):

    f = open(filename, 'w')
    s= "{\n\"tiles\": 20\n}"
    f.write(s)
    f.close()
```

When I call this function this way all is fine:

```
writeToFile('level_0.json', 1500, 15, layout)
```

However when I call it like this:

```
writeToFile('Level_0.json', 1500, 15, layout)
```

the file is still written as `level_0.json`

How can I get the resulting filename to be upper case? If it makes any difference I'm using OSX and Python 2.7.6.

Comment: If the file already exists when you open it, it keeps the old name. If you delete the file first it will get the new name. Oops, that's for Windows - I thought OSX was based on *nix and being case sensitive you'd get two different files.

Comment: HFS+ is, by default, not case sensitive but is case preserving. from [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1037142).

Comment: I deleted the file `level_0.json` from the directory and then re-ran the program and it worked...weird, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- HFS+ is, by default, not case sensitive but is case preserving. from [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1037142) - [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin)
- Therefore, if the file already exists when you open it, it keeps the old name. If you delete the file first it will get the new name. - [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom)

Comment: I moved the answers from the comments section in order that OP would have something to accept. Note this answer is a "community wiki". Anyone may edit, and no points are awarded to anybody.